# Moran test results - rejection of H0

Tags: spatial-statistics, gis-principle, moran-index

I started with a linear model (lm) and I want to make some spatials models so I tried first a Moran test to lm.

Can we reject the null hypothesis with a p value of 0.11 in order to continue working and trying spatial models?

I have tried several specifications for lms and all of them have bigger p values.

I want just to justify why I will try spatial models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by no means an expert in spatial statistics. But, from what I recall from university, a p-value of 0.11 is not statistically significant. Typically, you would reject the null hypothesis if the p-value was 0.5 or lower.

However, it also depends on your z-score. Just having a p-value isn't necessarily enough to know whether to reject or accept the null hypothesis. I would assume that whatever software you are using for the Moran test would also give you a z-value.

Esri has a [**page**](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/what-is-a-z-score-what-is-a-p-value.htm) describing z-score and p-value.

And this [**page**](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/h-how-spatial-autocorrelation-moran-s-i-spatial-st.htm) explains how Spatial Autocorrelation works.

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of analyses you should only reject the null hypothesis if the p-value is less than the .05 alpha level.  In some industries, such as healthcare, a p-value even lower than .05 may be applied.  You should definitely not claim that any p-value over .05 or even .10  is statistically significant. I suppose you could continue with your spatial analysis as long as you make it clear that you have a confidence interval below 90%.

[Here](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/understanding-statistics/what-can-you-say-when-your-p-value-is-greater-than-005) is useful information regarding high p-values.